# Closing of multiple port using express app

Tags: node.js, express

I am running multiple server instance of a app on different port using "npm run node_1 & npm run node_2 &" , this successfully runs my localhost on 3001 and 3002 . But when i try to close it using CTRL+C it only closes the first defined port and the other one still remains in use giving error below , when i run it again

[nodemon] starting `node ./networkNode.js 3002 http://localhost:3002`
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3002

```
My package.json :

"scripts": {
    "node_1": "nodemon --watch . -e js ./networkNode.js 3001 
           http://localhost:3001",
    "node_2": "nodemon --watch . -e js ./networkNode.js 3002 
           http://localhost:3002",
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` after a command runs it as a background job. Theres a number of commands available to manage these which are detailed [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html)

What may be easier is to use the NPM [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package to start these processes instead. As killing `concurrently` with `Ctrl+C` will kill all jobs it started.

Comment: concurrently worked for me thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run multiple process using `&`, only 1 process gets attached to the terminal AFAIK, and when you press **ctrl+c**, only the attached process gets [SIGINT signal event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events). You would have better luck running those process using a process manager like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or if you don't want anything heavy use [run-all package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all).